# Messagebox doesn't show

Tags: c#, mysql

I've created a database using mysql, on my form1 there are two textboxes username and password and a login button. My program retrieves information from database and if the data s matches it logs in else an messagebox should pop up telling that username of password is wrong ( which it doesn't show)

before posting the code: 
I've declared: the following

```
public int logid;
public int loginid(strign name) // to set logid the id of the user
public void loginfun();        //  checks the data and logs in if id and password matches, else should give an error message.
```

and my code is as follows:

```
public int loginid(string name)
    {
        string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=ozturk;Uid=_____;pwd=_____";
        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        string getid = "SELECT username,id from ozturk.admin WHERE username='" + name + "'";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getid, mcon);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        mcon.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            if (myReader["username"].ToString() == name)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(myReader["id"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }


public void loginfun()
    {
        string conString ="Server=localhost;Database=ozturk;Uid=_____;pwd=_____";
        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ozturk.admin";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectCommand,mcon);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        mcon.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                if (myReader["username"].ToString() == txtuserid.Text && myReader["password"].ToString() == txtpassword.Text)
                {
                    // set logid to userid
                    logid = loginid(myReader["username"].ToString());
                    string updateCommand = "UPDATE ozturk.admin SET status = 'on' WHERE id='" + logid + "' ";

                    MySqlConnection newcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(updateCommand, newcon);
                    MySqlDataReader myReader2;
                    newcon.Open();
                    myReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                    Anasayfa anasayf = new Anasayfa();
                    anasayf.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is: My program logs in and opens the other form if the username and the password is correct however it doesn't do anything if the username or password is wrong, What am I missing here? any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Use always SqlParameters

Comment: I didm't understant what you were trying to tell, I'm very new to mysql and only know the basics so this is what I could do

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, here is what I've done: I've changed my login function from void to bool: here is the latest code:

```
public bool loginfun()
    {
        string conString ="Server=localhost;Database=ozturk;Uid=_____;pwd=_____";
        MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ozturk.admin";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectCommand,mcon);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        mcon.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                if (myReader["username"].ToString() == txtuserid.Text && myReader["password"].ToString() == txtpassword.Text)
                {
                    // giriş yapan kişinin id si
                    logid = loginid(myReader["username"].ToString());
                    string updateCommand = "UPDATE ozturk.admin SET status = 'on' WHERE id='" + logid + "' ";

                    MySqlConnection newcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(updateCommand, newcon);
                    MySqlDataReader myReader2;
                    newcon.Open();
                    myReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();


                    return true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

and inside the login button the code is as follows:

```
if (loginfun() == true)
        {
            Anasayfa anasayf = new Anasayfa();
            anasayf.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
        }
```

Thank you everyone for the tips

Answer (score -1):

This is your code:

```
 bool flag = false;
    while (myReader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (myReader["username"].ToString() == txtuserid.Text && myReader["password"].ToString() == txtpassword.Text)
                    {
                        // set the flag to true, is credentials match and break from the loop
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                        // set logid to userid
                        logid = loginid(myReader["username"].ToString());
                        string updateCommand = "UPDATE ozturk.admin SET status = 'on' WHERE id='" + logid + "' ";

                        MySqlConnection newcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(updateCommand, newcon);
                        MySqlDataReader myReader2;
                        newcon.Open();
                        myReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                        Anasayfa anasayf = new Anasayfa();
                        anasayf.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
                    throw;
                }
            }
            if(!flag)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
            }
```

Comment: I dont think iterating over a whole table in code is a good solution for a single login check.

Comment: I was just using the code of the user, I just found his msitake.

Comment: Why did you vote it down? My answer actually addresses the issue.

Comment: I didn't it was someone else I guess

Comment: Okay, please accept my answer it it addresses your issue.